# how to prevent retrieval of data from disk in a $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

In the `$lookup` stage of my aggregation pipeline, it needs to join based on `_id`, which is indexed on the joined collection. The purpose is to simply check whether there are any matches in joined collection. The actual data of the joined document(s) does not matter, and hence does not need to be retrieved at all whether on disk or RAM.

So, how do I write the `$lookup` to ensure that data is never retrieved from disk. Instead, a value of `true` can be returned if matching records were found?

EDITED:

Retrieving data from disk is expensive, hence the reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $lookup, use a pipeline that starts with a $project stage that includes only the _id field.

```
{$lookup: {
    from: "targetCollection",
    localField: "fieldName",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "matched",
    pipeline: [
        { $project: {_id: 1}},
        { $count: "count" }
    ]
}}
```

The query executor should realize that all of the data needed to satisfy that part of the query can be obtained from the index, and not load any documents.

Note: this assumes you are using MongoDB 5.0+

Comment: what if a $match stage is needed inside of the pipeline?

Comment: $match is allowed, but If you match on any field that is not in the index, it will have to fetch the document from disk.